# Question for function FindMaximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need some advice on using the function FindMaximum as follows.

I find the function y(x) from a differential equation as below, and then for each c and each xMax I have different solutions y(x) and I evaluate Abs(y(x=xMax)).

```
test[a_, xMax_] := Module[{temp},
  temp = NDSolve[{y'[x] == c* y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
    y, {x, 0, xMax}];

  (y /. temp)[[1]][xMax] // Abs (*Abs(y(x=xMax))*)
  ]
```

I fix xMax = 30 and narrow c from 0.2 to 0.5 and I want to find c that gives me the largest Abs(y(x=xMax)).

```
FindMaximum[{test[c, 30], 0.2 < c < 0.5}, {c, 0.3}]
```

But the code doesn't work. Errors appear like[image]
How can I resolve this.

Comment: Replace `test[c_, xMax_] := Module[...` with `Clear[test];test[c_?NumericQ, xMax_] := Module[...` and see if your problem goes away. That `Clear[test]` removes any cached old definition of `test` and the `?NumericQ` forces evaluation to be done on numeric constants given to `c` instead of any possible symbolic evaluation of `c` without an assigned numeric constant value.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Bill: Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 2):

`ParametricNDSolve` is well suited for such problems.  Try

```
test = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == c*y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y[xMax], 
    {x, 0, xMax}, {c, xMax}]
FindMaximum[{Abs@test[c, 30], 0.2 < c < 0.5}, {c, 0.3}]
(* {0.480145, {c -> 0.2}} *)
```

By the way, the code in the question contains an error.  Replace `test[a_, xMax_]` by `test[c_, xMax_]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and very nice guidance above.